# What is the range (distance) two devices can be connected using the iOS gamekit framework

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, gamekit

I would like to develop an app using iOS gamekit library and I am curious to know what the maximum range is between the two devices.  How far can they stay connected and communicating?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go check the bluetooth and wi-fi specs, rather than thinking that the GK decides how far you can play:)

Comment: You're welcome..However, Class 1: range up to 100 meters Class 2: up to 30 meters range...I remember that iPhone has Class2.